# Bayesian inference adaptable to not mutually exlclusive events?

Tags: bayesian, inference

Say I have $n$ possible events that lead to $m$ observable effects.

The Bayesian inference hypothesis is that events are mutually exclusive and jointly exhaustive. Could I still be able to use Bayesian inference (modified, eventually) when more than one event occurs at some observation?

Real example:
$n$ possible faulty components on a single board with $m$ on-board test points that can result "in range" or "out of range," and I cannot *a priori* exclude that two components are faulty at the same time.

Comment: So for $n=2$ you want to estimate $p(n_1=0,n_2=0|m)$, $p(n_1=1,n_2=0|m)$, $p(n_1=0,n_2=1|m)$, etc. I don't understand how the Bayesian paradigm fails.

Comment: There is nothing in Bayesian statistics that prevents you from creating an event $E = A \cap B$ from two other events $A$ and $B$; indeed, being able to do so is pretty fundamental to statistics.  "Mutually exclusive and jointly exhaustive" reminds me of the Accenture paradigm for problem description "MECE" = mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive - but that's not statistical in nature either.

Comment: Generally in real systems (say electronic, mechanical), even if not likely, it is possible to have more than one faulty element at same time.

Comment: Generally in real systems (say electronic, mechanical), even if not likely, it is possible to have more than one faulty element at same time. The only way to do a rigorous analysis is to consider every distinct combination of more than one element to be an element itself. This would draw a too high complexity and assuming that only one component can be faulty at a time is a unavoidable choice, even if limiting, for practical use of inferential formulas.

Comment: Considering every fault pattern in n components, total number of possible configuration would be Sum[k from 1 to n](Dn,k). Fairly too much for practical use.